# Android Google maps v2 markers z order / z index

Tags: android, google-maps

I did investigate all similar topics, but none of them actually had solution to issue I have currently. Straight away, hack with showInfoWindow(); is not resolving this issue, as it brings to front only one marker.

**Requirements:**

I have 3 types of markers *RED, GREEN, BLUE*. All *RED* markers should be displayed on top of the *GREEN* and *BLUE*, all *GREEN* should be displayed on top of *BLUE*.

**Question:**

How it is possible to achieve this in android?  if it is not possible with google maps v2, is there any alternatives e.g. is it possible to integrate Google Maps JavaScript v3  and pass markers from java to JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, as of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0` you can set z-index of individual markers

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#june_27_2016